# How to show symbols in ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, no section header

Tags: c++, c, elf, nm

Got a file which I do not know how to list its symbols, file command says:

```
]# file <file-name>
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, no section header
```

`nm` and `nm -D` says no symbols in it.
How to get the symbols?

Comment: Looks like it is a fully-stripped binary with no symbols.  `objdump -a` will tell you what there is in the file (probably just a couple of program headers/segments).  `objdump -d` will disassemble the code in executable segments, which might give a few hints.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get the symbols?

The `nm -D` is *guaranteed* to not produce any output for a `statically linked` binary -- dynamic symbols are never present in such binaries.

The fact that `nm` produces no output and that `file` says `no section header` means that this binary is *fully stripped*, i.e. *all* symbols and section info has been removed from it.

There is no way to get symbols from *this* binary -- you need to get the original (unstipped) one if you need symbolic info.